# Log4J 2 XML configuration not writing to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4J 2 in a SpringBoot application.

The class performing the logging is:

```
package guru.springframework.blog.log4jproperties;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class PropertiesConfigurationDemo {
    private static Logger logger =LogManager.getLogger("PropertiesConfigurationDemo.class");
    public void performSomeTask(){
      logger.debug("This is a debug message");
      logger.info("This is an info message");
      logger.warn("This is a warn message");
      logger.error("This is an error message");
      logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
   }
}
```

My log4j2.xml is in src->main->resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <File name="A1" fileName="${log-path}/A1.log" >
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="guru.springframework.blog.log4jproperties" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="A1" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
 </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I call the performSomeTask() method on PropertiesConfigurationDemo, the log messages are sent to Console as:

```
7:39:12.619 [main] DEBUG PropertiesConfigurationDemo.class - This is a debug message
07:39:12.643 [main] INFO  PropertiesConfigurationDemo.class - This is an info message
07:39:12.647 [main] WARN  PropertiesConfigurationDemo.class - This is a warn message
07:39:12.653 [main] ERROR PropertiesConfigurationDemo.class - This is an error message
07:39:12.655 [main] ERROR PropertiesConfigurationDemo.class - This is a fatal message
```

Why are the log messages not sent to file? Even, if I set AppenderRef of the root logger to A1, still the messages are sent to Console.'

```
<Root level="info" additivity="false">
<AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
</Root>
```

It appears my log4j2.xml has some issues or is not getting picked up at all. Any help will be sincerely acknowledged.

Btw, I have the following log4j dependencies in my MAVEN POM.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks
Simanta

Answer (score 2):

I got it done. The issue was with POM dependencies.  I excluded the default logback classic and added log4j2. This what I modified.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My log4j2.xml is in src->main->resources is now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Configuration>
    <Properties>
      <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <File name="File" fileName="${log-path}/log4j2.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
              [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
            [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="guru.springframework.blog.log4jproperties"  level="debug"  additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"  level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And in my application class, I retrieved  the Logger as.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("guru.springframework.blog.log4jproperties");
```

Now, logging is getting directed both to console and file.